# Application works in local server but not in Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I have a static landing page (students/index.html.erb) that renders on my local server; however, when I push it to Heroku, the default public/index.html file renders instead of the landing page. When I delete public/index.html, public/500.html is served.

I'm struggling to troubleshoot this issue. Hopefully, the below information helps explain my situation:

**routes.rb:**

```
AlumniKickstarter::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :students

# match '/',  to: 'students#index'
root :to => 'students#index'
```

**Gemfile:**

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.13'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

group :development do
  gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.5'
end


# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'

  # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
  # gem 'therubyracer', :platforms => :ruby

  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
  gem 'twitter-bootstrap-rails'
  gem 'libv8', '~> 3.11.8'
  gem 'less-rails'
  gem 'therubyracer'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'

group :production do
  gem 'pg', '0.12.2'
end
```

**Output from running** `git push heroku master`:

```
Counting objects: 5, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (3/3), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 283 bytes, done.
Total 3 (delta 2), reused 0 (delta 0)

-----> Ruby/Rails app detected
-----> Installing dependencies using Bundler version 1.3.2
       Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin --deployment
       Using rake (10.0.4)
       Using i18n (0.6.1)
       Using multi_json (1.7.5)
       Using activesupport (3.2.13)
       Using builder (3.0.4)
       Using activemodel (3.2.13)
       Using erubis (2.7.0)
       Using journey (1.0.4)
       Using rack (1.4.5)
       Using rack-cache (1.2)
       Using rack-test (0.6.2)
       Using hike (1.2.2)
       Using tilt (1.4.1)
       Using sprockets (2.2.2)
       Using actionpack (3.2.13)
       Using mime-types (1.23)
       Using polyglot (0.3.3)
       Using treetop (1.4.12)
       Using mail (2.5.4)
       Using actionmailer (3.2.13)
       Using arel (3.0.2)
       Using tzinfo (0.3.37)
       Using activerecord (3.2.13)
       Using activeresource (3.2.13)
       Using coffee-script-source (1.6.2)
       Using execjs (1.4.0)
       Using coffee-script (2.2.0)
       Using rack-ssl (1.3.3)
       Using json (1.8.0)
       Using rdoc (3.12.2)
       Using thor (0.18.1)
       Using railties (3.2.13)
       Using coffee-rails (3.2.2)
       Using commonjs (0.2.6)
       Using jquery-rails (3.0.0)
       Using less (2.3.2)
       Using less-rails (2.3.3)
       Using libv8 (3.11.8.17)
       Using pg (0.12.2)
       Using bundler (1.3.2)
       Using rails (3.2.13)
       Using ref (1.0.5)
       Using sass (3.2.9)
       Using sass-rails (3.2.6)
       Using therubyracer (0.11.4)
       Using twitter-bootstrap-rails (2.2.6)
       Using uglifier (2.1.1)
       Your bundle is complete! It was installed into ./vendor/bundle
       Cleaning up the bundler cache.
-----> Writing config/database.yml to read from DATABASE_URL
-----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
       Running: rake assets:precompile
       rake aborted!
       Invalid CSS after "*/": expected identifier, was "/* Sections"
       (in /tmp/build_2d39py02gj5kc/app/assets/stylesheets/application.css)
       (sass):1268
       /tmp/build_2d39py02gj5kc/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.2.9/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:1148:in `expected'
       /tmp/build_2d39py02gj5kc/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.2.9/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:1084:in `expected'
       /tmp/build_2d39py02gj5kc/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.2.9/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:1066:in `expr!'
       /tmp/build_2d39py02gj5kc/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.2.9/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:660:in `reference_combinator'
       /tmp/build_2d39py02gj5kc/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.2.9/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:654:in `combinator'
       /tmp/build_2d39py02gj5kc/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.2.9/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:646:in `_selector'
       /tmp/build_2d39py02gj5kc/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.2.9/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:619:in `selector'
       /tmp/build_2d39py02gj5kc/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.2.9/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:603:in `selector_sequence'
       /tmp/build_2d39py02gj5kc/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.2.9/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:528:in `ruleset'
       /tmp/build_2d39py02gj5kc/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.2.9/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:553:in `block_child'
       /tmp/build_2d39py02gj5kc/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.2.9/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:546:in `block_contents'
       /tmp/build_2d39py02gj5kc/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.2.9/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:82:in `stylesheet'
       /tmp/build_2d39py02gj5kc/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.2.9/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:27:in `parse'
       /tmp/build_2d39py02gj5kc/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.2.9/lib/sass/engine.rb:342:in `_to_tree'
       /tmp/build_2d39py02gj5kc/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.2.9/lib/sass/engine.rb:315:in `_render'
       /tmp/build_2d39py02gj5kc/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.2.9/lib/sass/engine.rb:262:in `render'
       /tmp/build_2d39py02gj5kc/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sass-rails-3.2.6/lib/sass/rails/compressor.rb:12:in `compress'
       /tmp/build_2d39py02gj5kc/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/sprockets/compressors.rb:74:in `compress'
       /tmp/build_2d39py02gj5kc/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/processing.rb:243:in `block in css_compressor='
       /tmp/build_2d39py02gj5kc/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/processor.rb:29:in `call'
       /tmp/build_2d39py02gj5kc/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/processor.rb:29:in `evaluate'
       /tmp/build_2d39py02gj5kc/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/tilt-1.4.1/lib/tilt/template.rb:103:in `render'
       /tmp/build_2d39py02gj5kc/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/context.rb:193:in `block in evaluate'
       /tmp/build_2d39py02gj5kc/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/context.rb:190:in `each'
       /tmp/build_2d39py02gj5kc/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/context.rb:190:in `evaluate'
       /tmp/build_2d39py02gj5kc/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/bundled_asset.rb:26:in `initialize'
       /tmp/build_2d39py02gj5kc/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:252:in `new'
       /tmp/build_2d39py02gj5kc/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:252:in `build_asset'
       /tmp/build_2d39py02gj5kc/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/index.rb:93:in `block in build_asset'
       /tmp/build_2d39py02gj5kc/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/caching.rb:19:in `cache_asset'
       /tmp/build_2d39py02gj5kc/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/index.rb:92:in `build_asset'
       /tmp/build_2d39py02gj5kc/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:169:in `find_asset'
       /tmp/build_2d39py02gj5kc/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/index.rb:60:in `find_asset'
       /tmp/build_2d39py02gj5kc/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/sprockets/static_compiler.rb:19:in `block in compile'
       /tmp/build_2d39py02gj5kc/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:219:in `block in each_logical_path'
       /tmp/build_2d39py02gj5kc/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:206:in `block (2 levels) in each_file'
       /tmp/build_2d39py02gj5kc/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:196:in `each'
       /tmp/build_2d39py02gj5kc/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:196:in `each_entry'
       /tmp/build_2d39py02gj5kc/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:204:in `block in each_file'
       /tmp/build_2d39py02gj5kc/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:203:in `each'
       /tmp/build_2d39py02gj5kc/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:203:in `each_file'
       /tmp/build_2d39py02gj5kc/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:217:in `each_logical_path'
       /tmp/build_2d39py02gj5kc/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/sprockets/static_compiler.rb:18:in `compile'
       /tmp/build_2d39py02gj5kc/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:56:in `internal_precompile'
       /tmp/build_2d39py02gj5kc/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:70:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
       /tmp/build_2d39py02gj5kc/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:246:in `call'
       /tmp/build_2d39py02gj5kc/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:246:in `block in execute'
       /tmp/build_2d39py02gj5kc/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:241:in `each'
       /tmp/build_2d39py02gj5kc/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:241:in `execute'
       /tmp/build_2d39py02gj5kc/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:184:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
       /tmp/build_2d39py02gj5kc/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:177:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
       /tmp/build_2d39py02gj5kc/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:170:in `invoke'
       /tmp/build_2d39py02gj5kc/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:60:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
       /tmp/build_2d39py02gj5kc/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:246:in `call'
       /tmp/build_2d39py02gj5kc/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:246:in `block in execute'
       /tmp/build_2d39py02gj5kc/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:241:in `each'
       /tmp/build_2d39py02gj5kc/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:241:in `execute'
       /tmp/build_2d39py02gj5kc/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:184:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
       /tmp/build_2d39py02gj5kc/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:177:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
       /tmp/build_2d39py02gj5kc/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:170:in `invoke'
       /tmp/build_2d39py02gj5kc/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:23:in `invoke_or_reboot_rake_task'
       /tmp/build_2d39py02gj5kc/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:29:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
       /tmp/build_2d39py02gj5kc/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:246:in `call'
       /tmp/build_2d39py02gj5kc/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:246:in `block in execute'
       /tmp/build_2d39py02gj5kc/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:241:in `each'
       /tmp/build_2d39py02gj5kc/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:241:in `execute'
       /tmp/build_2d39py02gj5kc/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:184:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
       /tmp/build_2d39py02gj5kc/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:177:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
       /tmp/build_2d39py02gj5kc/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:170:in `invoke'
       /tmp/build_2d39py02gj5kc/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:143:in `invoke_task'
       /tmp/build_2d39py02gj5kc/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:101:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
       /tmp/build_2d39py02gj5kc/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:101:in `each'
       /tmp/build_2d39py02gj5kc/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:101:in `block in top_level'
       /tmp/build_2d39py02gj5kc/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:110:in `run_with_threads'
       /tmp/build_2d39py02gj5kc/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:95:in `top_level'
       /tmp/build_2d39py02gj5kc/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:73:in `block in run'
       /tmp/build_2d39py02gj5kc/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:160:in `standard_exception_handling'
       /tmp/build_2d39py02gj5kc/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:70:in `run'
       Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile:primary
       (See full trace by running task with --trace)
       Precompiling assets failed, enabling runtime asset compilation
       Injecting rails31_enable_runtime_asset_compilation
       Please see this article for troubleshooting help:
       http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails31_heroku_cedar#troubleshooting
-----> Rails plugin injection
       Injecting rails_log_stdout
       Injecting rails3_serve_static_assets
-----> Discovering process types
       Procfile declares types      -> (none)
       Default types for Ruby/Rails -> console, rake, web, worker

-----> Compiled slug size: 16.5MB
-----> Launching... done, v18
```

**Output from running `heroku logs`:**

```
2013-06-05T00:36:00.461519+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-06-05T00:36:00.461519+00:00 app[web.1]:     13:     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"></head>
2013-06-05T00:36:00.461519+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (couldn't find file 'twitter/bootstrap'
2013-06-05T00:36:00.461519+00:00 app[web.1]:     8: 
2013-06-05T00:36:00.461519+00:00 app[web.1]:     11:     <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>  
2013-06-05T00:36:00.461519+00:00 app[web.1]:   (in /app/app/assets/javascripts/application.js:15)):
2013-06-05T00:36:00.461519+00:00 app[web.1]:     10:     "all" %>
2013-06-05T00:36:00.461709+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-06-05T00:36:00.461709+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/students/index.html.erb:11:in `_app_views_students_index_html_erb__2877822377443894980_25032140'
2013-06-05T00:36:00.461709+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/students_controller.rb:7:in `index'
2013-06-05T00:36:00.461519+00:00 app[web.1]:     14: 
2013-06-05T00:36:00.625289+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=nameless-brook-8163.herokuapp.com fwd="108.94.165.104" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=15ms status=200 bytes=0
2013-06-05T00:38:03.006760+00:00 heroku[slugc]: Slug compilation started
2013-06-05T00:39:00.633949+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy 55bc80c by ...@...com
2013-06-05T00:39:00.680231+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v17 created by ...@...com
2013-06-05T00:39:00.720369+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy 55bc80c by ...@...com
2013-06-05T00:39:00.912400+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to starting
2013-06-05T00:39:01.298787+00:00 heroku[slugc]: Slug compilation finished
2013-06-05T00:39:04.149611+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2013-06-05T00:39:04.884975+00:00 app[web.1]:    /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:90:in `select'
2013-06-05T00:39:04.884975+00:00 app[web.1]: [2013-06-05 00:39:04] ERROR SignalException: SIGTERM
2013-06-05T00:39:07.278314+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rails server -p 11243`
2013-06-05T00:39:10.726893+00:00 app[web.1]: DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/config/environment.rb:5)
2013-06-05T00:39:10.726201+00:00 app[web.1]: DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/config/environment.rb:5)
2013-06-05T00:39:10.727170+00:00 app[web.1]: DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/config/environment.rb:5)
2013-06-05T00:39:13.485100+00:00 app[web.1]: => Call with -d to detach
2013-06-05T00:39:13.485100+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting WEBrick
2013-06-05T00:39:13.485100+00:00 app[web.1]: Connecting to database specified by DATABASE_URL
2013-06-05T00:39:13.485100+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 3.2.13 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:11243
2013-06-05T00:39:13.485100+00:00 app[web.1]: => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
2013-06-05T00:39:13.631678+00:00 app[web.1]: [2013-06-05 00:39:13] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
2013-06-05T00:39:13.632036+00:00 app[web.1]: [2013-06-05 00:39:13] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=2 port=11243
2013-06-05T00:39:13.631678+00:00 app[web.1]: [2013-06-05 00:39:13] INFO  ruby 1.9.2 (2011-07-09) [x86_64-linux]
2013-06-05T00:39:13.833652+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2013-06-05T00:39:15.167055+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R12 (Exit timeout) -> At least one process failed to exit within 10 seconds of SIGTERM
2013-06-05T00:39:15.167218+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping remaining processes with SIGKILL
2013-06-05T00:39:17.251593+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
2013-06-05T00:40:55.236434+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/ host=nameless-brook-8163.herokuapp.com fwd="108.94.165.104" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=25ms status=200 bytes=52
2013-06-05T00:47:11.520833+00:00 heroku[slugc]: Slug compilation started
2013-06-05T00:48:02.351232+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy 7aed133 by ...@...com
2013-06-05T00:48:02.391620+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v18 created by ...@...com
2013-06-05T00:48:02.439419+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy 7aed133 by ...@...com
2013-06-05T00:48:03.099430+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to starting
2013-06-05T00:48:04.236672+00:00 heroku[slugc]: Slug compilation finished
2013-06-05T00:48:05.481753+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rails server -p 31179`
2013-06-05T00:48:07.091383+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2013-06-05T00:48:08.065072+00:00 app[web.1]: [2013-06-05 00:48:08] ERROR SignalException: SIGTERM
2013-06-05T00:48:08.065072+00:00 app[web.1]:    /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:90:in `select'
2013-06-05T00:48:08.605700+00:00 app[web.1]: DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/config/environment.rb:5)
2013-06-05T00:48:08.605700+00:00 app[web.1]: DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/config/environment.rb:5)
2013-06-05T00:48:08.606072+00:00 app[web.1]: DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/config/environment.rb:5)
2013-06-05T00:48:11.204596+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting WEBrick
2013-06-05T00:48:11.204596+00:00 app[web.1]: => Call with -d to detach
2013-06-05T00:48:11.204596+00:00 app[web.1]: Connecting to database specified by DATABASE_URL
2013-06-05T00:48:11.204596+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 3.2.13 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:31179
2013-06-05T00:48:11.204596+00:00 app[web.1]: => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
2013-06-05T00:48:11.362404+00:00 app[web.1]: [2013-06-05 00:48:11] INFO  ruby 1.9.2 (2011-07-09) [x86_64-linux]
2013-06-05T00:48:11.362811+00:00 app[web.1]: [2013-06-05 00:48:11] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=2 port=31179
2013-06-05T00:48:11.362404+00:00 app[web.1]: [2013-06-05 00:48:11] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
2013-06-05T00:48:11.701746+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2013-06-05T00:48:18.235548+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping remaining processes with SIGKILL
2013-06-05T00:48:18.235327+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R12 (Exit timeout) -> At least one process failed to exit within 10 seconds of SIGTERM
2013-06-05T00:48:20.742700+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 108.94.165.104 at 2013-06-05 00:48:20 +0000
2013-06-05T00:48:20.812760+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
2013-06-05T00:48:20.911791+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by StudentsController#index as HTML
2013-06-05T00:48:23.532993+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/ host=nameless-brook-8163.herokuapp.com fwd="108.94.165.104" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=2812ms status=500 bytes=0
2013-06-05T00:48:23.528705+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 2617ms
2013-06-05T00:48:23.530862+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (couldn't find file 'twitter/bootstrap'
2013-06-05T00:48:23.530862+00:00 app[web.1]:     8: 
2013-06-05T00:48:23.528528+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered students/index.html.erb within layouts/application (2426.4ms)
2013-06-05T00:48:23.530862+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-06-05T00:48:23.530862+00:00 app[web.1]:     11:     <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>  
2013-06-05T00:48:23.531057+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/students/index.html.erb:11:in `_app_views_students_index_html_erb__2577290460858559341_22374820'
2013-06-05T00:48:23.531057+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/students_controller.rb:7:in `index'
2013-06-05T00:48:23.530862+00:00 app[web.1]:     13:     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"></head>
2013-06-05T00:48:23.530862+00:00 app[web.1]:     9:     <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media =>  
2013-06-05T00:48:23.530862+00:00 app[web.1]:     12:     <%= csrf_meta_tags %>  
2013-06-05T00:48:23.530862+00:00 app[web.1]:   (in /app/app/assets/javascripts/application.js:15)):
2013-06-05T00:48:23.530862+00:00 app[web.1]:     10:     "all" %>
2013-06-05T00:48:23.531057+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-06-05T00:48:23.531057+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-06-05T00:48:23.530862+00:00 app[web.1]:     14: 
2013-06-05T00:56:55.475742+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 108.94.165.104 at 2013-06-05 00:56:55 +0000
2013-06-05T00:56:55.487310+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by StudentsController#index as HTML
2013-06-05T00:56:55.503214+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/ host=nameless-brook-8163.herokuapp.com fwd="108.94.165.104" dyno=web.1 connect=10ms service=38ms status=500 bytes=0
2013-06-05T00:56:55.502595+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-06-05T00:56:55.502595+00:00 app[web.1]:     8: 
2013-06-05T00:56:55.502595+00:00 app[web.1]:     13:     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"></head>
2013-06-05T00:56:55.502595+00:00 app[web.1]:     11:     <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>  
2013-06-05T00:56:55.502595+00:00 app[web.1]:     12:     <%= csrf_meta_tags %>  
2013-06-05T00:56:55.502595+00:00 app[web.1]:   (in /app/app/assets/javascripts/application.js:15)):
2013-06-05T00:56:55.502595+00:00 app[web.1]:     14: 
2013-06-05T00:56:55.499474+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered students/index.html.erb within layouts/application (7.3ms)
2013-06-05T00:56:55.499474+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 13ms
2013-06-05T00:56:55.502595+00:00 app[web.1]:     9:     <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media =>  
2013-06-05T00:56:55.502595+00:00 app[web.1]:     10:     "all" %>
2013-06-05T00:56:55.502825+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/students/index.html.erb:11:in `_app_views_students_index_html_erb__2577290460858559341_22374820'
2013-06-05T00:56:55.502825+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-06-05T00:56:55.502825+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-06-05T00:56:55.502595+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (couldn't find file 'twitter/bootstrap'
2013-06-05T00:56:55.502825+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/students_controller.rb:7:in `index'
```

**Misc.**

After scouring related StackOverflow posts, I tried running **rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=production** to no avail.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# Gems used only for assets and not in production environments by default.
```

So, You should add gem twitter-bootstrap outside of any group and precompile before deploying.

```
  gem 'twitter-bootstrap-rails'
```